# Difference of Ranges

Tags: javascript, algorithm, set, set-intersection, set-difference

If I have the following arrays, with each element representing pairs of integer ranges:

```
var a = [[0, 47], [50, 51], [53, 53], [55, 55], [58, 97], [101, 101], [103, 1114111]];
var b = [[48, 57], [97, 102]];
```

I'm using [this code](https://ideone.com/3SAKLc) to **compute the intersection**:

```
var output = [];

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
    for (var j = 0; j < b.length; ++j) {
        var intersection = [
        Math.max(a[i][0], b[j][0]),
        Math.min(a[i][1], b[j][1]), ];

        if (intersection[0] <= intersection[1]) {
            output.push(intersection)
        }
    }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(output));

[ [ 50, 51 ], [ 53, 53 ], [ 55, 55 ], [ 97, 97 ], [ 101, 101 ] ]
```

I also need to **compute the *difference*** (all values 0..1114111 except the ranges that intersect above).

What's an efficient way of doing that?

Comment: Did you try that code? What happened/was the problem? What results were you expecting?

Comment: @Xotic750 it's O(n^2) where O(n log n) is possible.

Comment: @Xotic750: The code I linked works flawlessly (you can see its output on stdout), but it computes the intersection, not the *difference*, which is what I'm trying to figure out. I'll write the expected difference output in a bit.

Comment: You need to make it clear what the algorithm you need should do. Please do not include code that solves a different problem?  It's very confusing

Comment: @NiklasB. The intersection? Could you link me to that O(n log n) implementation? I will need to compute intersections of ranges as well, so it would be helpful too.

Comment: @Alix no you can't do crosswise intersection in O (n log n) since the output can be larger than that. It's not clear what you mean by "difference". Do you mean all-to-all here as well? I'm asking bc "How can I find all the ranges that do not intercept any of the arrays?" Sounds entirely different and completely unrelated to your code example

Comment: @NiklasB.: Sorry, with the edit Xotic750 did it came out as if I wanted to compute the intersection. Disregard that, I want to compute the difference - the only way I posted my intersection code is because it's the way I will do it if I can't find any better way of doing the same: get all values and remove the values that do intersect. I've updated the question, hopefully it's clearer now.

Comment: Post your code for calculating the `difference`, and a description of the problem you are having with it, rather than posting working code for calculating the `intersection` and asking others to write your missing code.

Comment: Oh ok. Yes you can compute the intersection as well in O (n log n) with the same algorithm that is included  in my answer. Just keep separate counts for a and b and outlut intervals where `min { count_a, count_b } > 0`

Comment: @Xotic750 he didn't ask for code. His code yields a simple but obviously inefficient algorithm to solve the difference problem (difference = intersection with complement). I don't see what your problem is, I think this is more about the approach than the implementation.

Comment: Probably similar confusion as you experienced with this question. If that is the case then this question is better suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Xotic750: I think I have explained the problem: I don't know how to efficiently compute the difference and I'm looking for advice on doing that. Given that the difference is universe - intersection, my naive implementation would go something like this: 1) create an array `diff`, 2) go though every range in `a` and `b` and append all the values within to the `diff` array, 3) loop through the `intersection` array and remove all values within from the `diff` array. It's a brute-force approach and quite convoluted, but I could write it down if it makes the question clearer.

Comment: @Alix: "all values 0..1114111 except the ranges that intersect above" is trivial, just iterate over the list of intervals `(l_1, r_1), (l_2, r_2), ...` and output `(r_1, l_2), (r_2, l_3), ...`. It confuses me that you would ask about this. Is it really a different problem you are having?

Comment: @Xotic750: That's nonsense, codereview is not about algorithms and asymptotical improvements

Comment: @NiklasB.: Sorry about all the confusion! I don't think that would work, but let me try your suggestion and I will try to explain this better.

Comment: @NiklasB So you think the question is a mathematical one? [asymptotical`](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/asymptotical), and the most efficient algorithm for solving the `difference`? That still doesn't seem to fit truly within the scope of SO from what I understand. I don't see where the problem is with the code that has been provided, do you?

Comment: @Xotic750 it has suboptimal asymptotic complexity (it's "slow")

Comment: Ok, so his routine has no fault, it works, but it is slow. He would like to improve his routine and would like us to review the code and suggest how to improve it (make it "faster")?

Comment: @Xotic750 I guess that's what it comes down to. What's notable is that we can even propose a better algorithm (polylog linear instead of quadratic) and not just constant factor micro optimization

Comment: So this is a question that is more suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ , I was not talking "nonsense", or perhaps it belongs to some other sister site, perhaps a `mathematical` one.

Comment: @Xotic codereview is definitely the wrong place. I feel stackoverflow is the best fit (the algorithm tag is full of these types of questions). I think computerscience stackexchange is an even better fit but it's still beta

Comment: Perhaps it is just the [tag:javascript] tag that is causing me to feel that this question is "wrongly" suited here, now that you have added [tag:algorithm]

Comment: You might want to consider revisiting this question and check out the answer ;)

Comment: @NiklasB. Indeed, apologies for the delay, and thanks so much for the help. I actually learnt something new. =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observation: "all values 0..1114111 except the ranges that intersect above" is actually trivial, you just iterate over the intersection and output its complement (connect end points to the start points of the following intervals).

So your problem reduces to finding the intersection faster. Use  a sweep line algorithm:

1. Create a list of events `(t, x, y)` where `t` is the border point of an interval and `x` is 1 if the interval came from `a` and 2 if it came from `b`. `y` is 1 if the border point is a starting point or -1 if it is an end point.
2. Sort lexicographically by `(t, -y)`
3. Set `count[1] = count[2] = 0`
4. Iterate through the event points. Update `count[x] += y`.

Now the result are the ranges where `count[1] > 0` and `count[2] > 0` at the same time.

The complexity is `O(n log n)`. Here's a code example: http://jsfiddle.net/QA5FY/14/ Thanks to user Xotic750 for providing the basic implementation.

Javascript

```
var a = [
    [0, 47],
    [50, 51],
    [53, 53],
    [55, 55],
    [58, 97],
    [101, 101],
    [103, 1114111]
];

var b = [
    [48, 57],
    [97, 102]
];

var evts = [];

function add(arr, x) {
    arr.forEach(function (pair) {
        evts.push({
            t: pair[0],
            x: x,
            y: 1
        }, {
            t: pair[1],
            x: x,
            y: -1
        });
    });
}

add(a, 0);
add(b, 1);

evts.sort(function (a, b) {
    return (a.t != b.t) ? (a.t - b.t) : (b.y - a.y);
});

var last = -1;
var count = [0, 0];
var res = [];

for (var i = 0; i < evts.length; ++i) {
    count[evts[i].x] += evts[i].y;
    if (count[evts[i].x] === 1 && count[evts[i].x ^ 1] > 0) last = i;
    else if (count[0] === 0 || count[1] === 0) {
        if (last >= 0) res.push([evts[last].t, evts[i].t]);
        last = -1;
    }
}

res.forEach(function (pair) {
    console.log(pair[0] + " " + pair[1]);
});
```

Output

```
50 51
53 53
55 55
97 97
101 101
```

Comment: Ah, I was staring at this trying to understand if elements of `a` and `b` were in the same `t`. The edit you just made makes sense, I'll try it in a couple of hours. Should #2 not sort by `x` too?

Comment: @Alix: At first I stated an algorithm to compute the complement of the union of a and b. Now this is an algorithm to compute the intersection of a and b. No you don't need to sort by `x`, it just marks the source of the interval. You sort by `-y` to prevent zero-length intervals but it's not necessary for correctness, you could also just sort by `t`

Comment: BTW, when I said all values 0..1114111, I was overlooking it. It should actually be all values are defined in the ranges so, in this case I think it's the same, but if the last element of `a` was `200, 1114111` for instance it would be different.

Comment: @AlixAxel: Sure, what I'm saying that computing the complement of a non-overlapping list of intervals is pretty trivial

Comment: @Niklas B. Have I understood your pseudo-code correctly? [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/QA5FY/)

Comment: @Xotic750 looks like it, yes. I haven't checked your compare function though, it's a bit wordy.  I'm also on  a mobile phone so I can't really test it. One thing though: you would probably want to select only those events where the condition becomes true and those where the condition becomes false. Those are the start and end points of the resulting interval list, respectively.

Comment: Ok, so basically `this[1] !== 0 && this[2] !== 0` rather than `this[1] > 0 && this[2] > 0`. I didn't make any attempt to optimise, just follow your pseudo.code.

Comment: @Xotic: no that's equivalent to your original code. But this way you only get the event points of the intersection. You can't reconstruct the solution from that. You need to record where the condition `this [1] > 0 and this [2] > 0` becomes true and where it becomes false again (the start and end points of the solution intervals)

Comment: Hmm, then I'm confused at your final step because I get no results, but for `!== 0` gives me results which I can then split into start-end pairs - [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/982fF/) - it then gives me `[[47,97],[103,1114111]]` but I'm not sure what the actual answer to the OP's question should be.

Comment: @Xotic if you get different results you have a bug because you should never get negative counts. Also, you can't split the points into start-end pairs if you use that condition. You need to keep only the points where the value of that boolean condition changes

Comment: @Xotic i am pretty sure your compare function is wromg. Maybe you misinterpreted "lexicographically"? Obviously you can't compare numbers after casting them to strings.

Comment: You want to do something like `a.t != b.t ? ( a.t - b.t) : (b.y - a.y)`

Comment: @Xotic: exactly: `(x,y) < (w, z) <=> x < w or (x = w and y < z)`it has nothing to do with strings

Comment: Ok, so you actually sort [`numerically`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number) rather than [`lexicographically`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) (== alphabetically).

Comment: @xotic have you actually read the wikipedia article? The section "definition" is of particular intetest. Lexicographical order is a total order defined on the cartedian product of two totally ordered sets. It has nothing to do with alphabets or strings.

Comment: I did indeed and some others, and they all seem to say in summary `In mathematics, lexicographical order is a means of ordering sequences in a manner analogous to that used to produce alphabetical order.`. So not sure what I have missed.

Comment: @Xotic: What you cite there is a very informal and ambiguous explanation and its also misleading since in this example a default alphabetical order on the represented strings is the same as the lexicographical order on the represented tuples of digits. That's not true for the general case, for example `(10, 1) > (2, 0)` in lexicographical order on integer tuples, but `"(10, 1)" < "(2, 0)"` in alphabetical string order. If in doubt, just [check the definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order#Definition)

Comment: @Xotic: "in a manner analogous to that used to produce alphabetical order" that doesn't mean it's the same as alphabetical order. It means it's a *generalization* of alphabetical order

Comment: Ok, I'm a little tired to get my head into that just now so will take it again when I am somewhat more rested. But finally, here is a [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/difference-of-ranges) of the OP's original and the routine given here using the test values given by the OP.

Comment: @Xotic: You need to try it with larger inputs to see any real difference.

Comment: I was hoping the OP (or any interested parties) may update the test with something larger.

Comment: @Xotic: http://jsperf.com/difference-of-ranges/3 As you can see it's a bit pointless to compare algorithms with different asymptotic complexities. You can *always* find an input where *any* given `O(n log n)` algorithm will be faster than *any* given `Ω(n^2)` algorithm by orders of magnitude. That's pretty much the definition :)

Comment: Indeed, but it seems to give good evidence that this algorithm is indeed faster (especially with larger sets of data)